# NLP: Tokenize : TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, chatbot, tokenize

> **I also tried .apply(str) and .astype(str) before tokenization, yet I get TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.**

---

```
data.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column           Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------           --------------  ----- 
 0   tag              8 non-null      object
 1   clean_patterns   8 non-null      object
 2   clean_responses  8 non-null      object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 320.0+ bytes
```

---

> **I am trying to word_tokenize the data for the NLP chatbot.**

---

```
print(word_tokenize(data))
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 print(word_tokenize(data))
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize_*init*_.py in
> word_tokenize(text, language, preserve_line)
> 128     :type preserve_line: bool
> 129     """
> --> 130     sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
> 131     return [
> 132         token for sent in sentences for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize_*init*_.py in
> sent_tokenize(text, language)
> 106     """
> 107     tokenizer = load("tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle".format(language))
> --> 108     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
> 109
> 110
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in tokenize(self,
> text, realign_boundaries)    1272         Given a text, returns a list
> of the sentences in that text.    1273         """
> -> 1274         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))    1275     1276     def debug_decisions(self,
> text):
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in
> sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries)    1326
> follows the period.    1327         """
> -> 1328         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]    1329     1330     def _slices_from_text(self,
> text):
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in (.0)
> 1326         follows the period.    1327         """
> -> 1328         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]    1329     1330     def _slices_from_text(self,
> text):
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in
> span_tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)    1316         if
> realign_boundaries:    1317             slices =
> self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
> -> 1318         for sl in slices:    1319             yield (sl.start, sl.stop)    1320
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in
> _realign_boundaries(self, text, slices)    1357         """    1358         realign = 0
> -> 1359         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):    1360             sl1 = slice(sl1.start + realign, sl1.stop)    1361             if not
> sl2:
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _pair_iter(it)
> 314     it = iter(it)
> 315     try:
> --> 316         prev = next(it)
> 317     except StopIteration:
> 318         return
>
> D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in
> _slices_from_text(self, text)    1330     def _slices_from_text(self, text):    1331         last_break = 0
> -> 1332         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):    1333
> context = match.group() + match.group("after_tok")    1334
> if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: You're calling word_tokenize on the dataframe, which isn't a str or bytes object. Did you mean to run it on a column in each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO ;)
Given the following dataframe `data` and the function `word_tokenize` you must do

```
import pandas as pd
def word_tokenize(sentence):
  return sentence.split()
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['bar bar bar foo', 
                                 'foo foo foo bar', 124],
                        'col2': [12, 13, 14]})
```

applying the function on `col1` in the simplest way possible

```
df['col1'].astype(str).apply(word_tokenize)
#ouput
0    [bar, bar, bar, foo]
1    [foo, foo, foo, bar]
2                   [124]
Name: col1, dtype: objec
```

first changing type to `str` second apply the function on every single element. The output would be `pandas.core.series.Series`